# Vectorize nested for loops in R (for multi class logistic loss calculation)

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning, vectorization

I am calculating the cost for a data set. Is there any way to simplify this nested for loop? Should I use apply or matrix multiplication?

More Background: this is muti-class logistic loss will be used in machine learning. and y_m is a indicator matrix that derived from label y (classification for 10 labels). I am simplify the problem to have a minimal reproducible code by randomly generate h2 and y.

```
h2=matrix(runif(5000*10),ncol=10)
y=round(runif(5000)*9)+1

y_m <- matrix(0,ncol=10,nrow=length(y))
y_m[cbind(1:length(y),y)] <- 1

J=0
for(i in 1:5000){
  for(k in 1:10){
    J=J-y_m[i,k]*log(h2[i,k])-(1-y_m[i,k])*log(1-h2[i,k]);
  }
}
J
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
J <- sum( - y_m * log(h2) - (1-y_m) * log(1-h2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/glmEnsemble")
?glmEnsemble::multiclass_logloss
```